# It is correct to say "I want to monitorize a server"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, expression-choice

I think I've read somewhere something like "I want to monitorize this web-server". It seems that the world actually exists: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monitorize but when I write it on Grammarly or similar software it recommends me changing it by "monitor", like "I want to monitor this server". But monitor sounds to me like a Noun rather than a Verb.

What do you think?

Comment: Given the defintion of monitorize, I'd agree with Grammarly. Monitor has a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monitor#Verb) form. The no-standard word "monitorize" doesn't seem to give any additional meaning.

Comment: monitorize is also flagged as 'non standard' on wiktionary, which stands for "Not conforming to the language as accepted by the majority of its speakers." I work in IT in an English-speaking environment and I have never heard monitorize.

Comment: Is this the opposite of a "lights out" server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think many techies would interpret "monitorize" in the above sentence to mean that you want to install a monitor in the server software.  This is different from simply wanting to "monitor" the server.

Answer (score 0):

Let us start this tangle of meaning with

> Monitor = transitive verb
>
> to watch, keep track of, or check usually for a special purpose
>
> “Nurses monitored the patient's heart rate”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monitor)

Thus, one could monitor a server in the sense of checking or visualising its functioning, as suggested by your wiki quote. But how? The server would have to produce some external expression of its function: flashing lights, beeps, activations of machinery, or - more often - output of symbols to a monitor, now defined by:

> Monitor = an electronic device with a screen used for display (as of television pictures or computer information)
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monitor)

Thus, the server could be monitored if needed. The monitoring is optional.

However, to give a server an *inseparable* attribute of being able to be monitored, it would have to be monitorized, such that the monitor is always functional whenever the server functions. The monitor might be as simple as the flashing lights commonly seen on network servers and network switches: the server is monitorized by their presence and they can only be switched off by switching off the server.

Comment: Hello Anton, thanks for your response. In this case, I was answering a question for a person interested in a Software which is used to monitor servers (this is, to analyze their logs and report incidences when required). This software is installed in those servers. Is that the reason I thought it could be more accurate to say "you need to install X on those endpoints you want to monitorize"  rather than "those endpoints you want to monitor". Because the software will "monitorize". Based on your answer I think that my suppose was right even every single corrector say that monitorize is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a google search for monitorize doing give any dictionary results, and only https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monitorize, which you referenced, attempts to provide two definitions. Interestingly, the second is:

> *Misspelling* of monetarize.

So I would tend to agree with that and suggest that it is incorrect to say “I want to monitorize a server”.

Answer (score -1):

"Monitor" possesses a perfectly valid verb form when used in this context. The "-ize" prefix is used to make a transitive verb out of the adjective when the standalone word doesn't make sense.

**Example:** The Bureau ***standardized*** all the weights and measures in use.
**Or:** The ***amortized*** version of QuickSort sometimes works better.

Comment: Yes, and I usually use "monitor". Nevertheless, I would like to understand if it correct to say monitorize when "monitor" could be misinterpreted. For example, in the phrase: " You need to install X on those endpoints you want to monitor" vs " you need to install X on those endpoints you want to monitorize". I may be wrong.